# Powershell search millions of files as fast as possible

Tags: performance, file-system, search, powershell

I once asked a similar question but in C#. Now I have the same problem in powershell..

What is the fastest way, to search files newer than 15 minutes, in a file system with more than 1 million files?

Is there any faster way than using pipe?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Select Name, PSIsContainer, Directory, LastWriteTime, Length| where {($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15))}
```

I already cut off some attributes to minimize the object size. It still takes ages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you don't need to call Get-Date for every file. Just call it once at the beginning:

```
$t = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | 
    Select Name, PSIsContainer, Directory, LastWriteTime, Length | 
    where {($_.LastWriteTime -gt $t)}
```

That's saves about 10% (as measured by Measure-Command).

Secondly, you don't need to call Select-Object for each file either. Just change the processing order:

```
$t = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | 
    where {($_.LastWriteTime -gt $t)} |
    Select Name, PSIsContainer, Directory, LastWriteTime, Length
```

Thirdly, try increasing the buffer size using the OutBuffer parameter:

```
$t = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -OutBuffer 1000 | 
    where {($_.LastWriteTime -gt $t)} |
    Select Name, PSIsContainer, Directory, LastWriteTime, Length
```

I've used 1000, but you can experiment with the value.

Those three changes reduced the running time to under one half on my system.

Comment: Thank you. This saves a lot of time. I know the question is about powershell.
Nevertheless I found an even faster solution -> Batch. Batch does the whole thing 10 times faster.

Comment: @greenhoorn, do you mean batch files (cmd.exe)?

Comment: Yes, I do mean batch files.

Comment: @greenhoorn Do you want to post your solution? Using Batch files, that is.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne This post is over 2 y old. I'm not in possession of the solution anymore. I'm sure you will find it with google like I did.

Comment: No problem at all.  Was just curious.  Isn't that always the case.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.avianwaves.com/Blog/entryid/177/PowerShell-Quickly-Finding-the-Oldest-and-Newest-Files-in-a-Folder.aspx

On this website, I found an example that I prefer to most of the solutions that are easily found with Google search.

The key is in using foreach-object instead of pipelining where-object filters and sort operations.

From the link above:

```
$newdate = [DateTime]::MinValue
$newfn = ""
$path = "."
get-childitem $path | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime -gt $newdate -and -not $_.PSIsContainer) {
        $newfn = $_.Name
        $newdate = $_.LastWriteTime
    }
}
$output = ""
if ($newfn -ne "") { $output += "`nNewest: " + $newdate + " -- " + $newfn }
if ($output -eq "") { $output += "`nFolder is empty." }
$output + "`n"
```

Based on everything I have read, using dir command in a batch script is still fastest option, but I dont have the motivation to learn the subtleties of batch scripting to extract the properties I want and format them as I want.
PowerShell is easier to manage and GCI is great.

Using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem may be a good alternative if you found this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196937/how-to-speed-up-powershell-get-childitem-over-unc
see here for more details.